# Can't get WooCommerce customers by email

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

When I make an API call to get users by mail address, I get the error:

> "{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}"

All other calls like `/products/` or `/orders/` work without problem. Pretty Links in permalink settings are activated.

```
this.WooCommerce = WC({
  url: 'http://............./', 
  consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxxxxxx', 
  consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
  wpAPI: true, 
  queryStringAuth: true,
  verifySsl: true,
  version: 'wc/v2' 

checkEmail(){

let validEmail = false;

let reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

if(reg.test(this.newUser.email)){
  //email looks valid

  this.wooCommerce.getAsync("customers/email/"+ this.newUser.email).then( (data) => {
    console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.wooCommerce.getAsync("customers/email/"+ this.newUser.email).then( (data) => {
    console.log(data);
}
```

change this to====>>>

```
this.wooCommerce.getAsync("customers?email="+ this.newUser.email).then( (data) => {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.